# Is it possible to generate an inner class of a class to compile with an annotation processor?

Tags: java, android, annotations, annotation-processing

I am wondering if it would be possible to generate a class, via an annotation processor, that would be an inner class of a class to be compiled.

For instance, while compiling class `A`, generate class `A$Foo`. I wonder if there is a trick that could be used or not. I got the feeling that it might be possible to generate some source that will be compiled in the same byte code as an inner class would. And, at compile/runtime, the JVM would take it for an inner class, and allow accessing outer class private fields.

The idea behind that question, which is not a noobie question, though it may look more or less technical, is to be able to use the private visibility modifier for annotated fields like Dagger, ButterKnife, etc. The private modifier allowing to detect unused fields more easily, whereas package private protection hides them.

Or is there any workaround, any way to get the best of both words ?

Comment: No. You cannot modify existing source files, just create new ones. But I always name generated classes according to that scheme for example `SomeInterface$Impl` to indicate that this generated class belongs to `SomeInterface`.

Comment: But I know exactly what you mean, I play around a lot with annotation processing and use it alot in my libraries, and I just wish it would be possible.... I normally tend to generate private final implementation classes and then generate a public factory class which creates instances of those interfaces with the private implementation classes. You could call this a workaround..

Answer (score 3):

Given your use case, no.

An inner class is a normal Java class, living in a different .class file. When compiled, a hidden constructor param is added to the inner class constructor. Private fields in the outer class are made accessible by adding hidden accessor methods in the outer class. All of this happens at compile time.

The JVM has nothing to do with that. If you generate a class that "looks like an inner class of another class", that won't make the outer class fields accessible.

Comment: That's the general idea I have of the limitation. Actually adding a few javap -c dumps of inner and outer classes would help to consider this answer canonical.

Comment: Moreover, this only holds for the javac compiler, ecj AFAIK has a different mechanism to express the link between outer and inner classes.

Answer (score -2):

Private visibility is really just a hint to compiler.   There is no problem to access those fields at the runtime at all (like I do in my small dependency injector: https://github.com/ko5tik/andject)

And non-static inner classes on android are generally a bad idea as it used to have performance penalty.

At the compile time you could use source generation tool like xdoclet (though it became technically obsolete years ago,  but still occasionally used) and generate all the sources you need in advance before compiling them.

Comment: In the library you link to you are using reflection to perform the injection. In most cases this is exactly what you want to avoid when using annotation processing and code generation. And the code you generate has to be valid code, and valid code cannot access private fields.

Comment: Private visibility is not "*just a hint to compiler*". In the default case you can access private fields with reflection, but this can be disabled if your code is running in a context with another security manager. In that case `Field.setAccessible` throws `SecurityException`.